# GridView is not scrollable during dataBinding?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, gridview, windows-8

I'm creating a Windows 8 app (not a desktop one).
My problem is the following:
I have a GridView with a lot of items (received from a database). When you get to the page, where this GridView is shown, you will immediately see some data in it, but depending on your hardware, you won't be able to scroll it in the beginning, only after a few seconds (on a Surface this was 2-3 seconds). This is of course poor user experience.
  I thought, I'll use some progress bar or activity indicator to the user, but I don't know, when to stop showing it.

Is there some property, method, event or something, which could help me in finding out, at what point in time I can really start scrolling the `GridView`?

Answer (score 0):

**Example :**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView Name="listView" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">

                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=.}" Header="Whatever" Width="140"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention in the description, that it is a Windows 8 app (not a desktop one). I think your solution is suitable for a desktop app. As far as I see, it won't work in a store app (aka. "metro style").
I updated my question in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a perfect answer and if one exists I would like to know it too, but here is a couple suggestions:

- Use virtualization if at all possible. We had serious performance issues with Surface as well and switching to virtualizing panel helped a lot.
- You could try to listen for Loaded event on each of the items in your GridView, once you get 100% of items loaded it should be safe to enable scroll or hide progress UI.